# Maximilian's Earthen Grasp - can it attempt to restrain the same target multiple times?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

Maximilian's  Earthen Grasp requires a Strength saving throw to resist its effects:

> Choose an unoccupied space on the ground that you can see. A hand rises there and reaches for one creature you can see within 5 feet of it. The target must make a Strength save. On a failed save, the target takes 2d6 bludgeoning damage and is restrained for the spell's duration.

Per [This Q&A](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/124654/42959), Maximilian's Earthen grasp persists even after a creature succeeds on the initial save - and the spell allows for the caster to choose other targets on subsequent turns:

> As an action, you can cause the hand to reach for a different creature or to move to a different unoccupied space within range. The hand releases a restrained target if you do either.

**If the spell's target succeeds on the initial save, can the caster target them with the hand again on subsequent turns?**

(The reason this is in question is because of the use of "different creature" in the text describing how to retarget the spell)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## You can attempt to grab the same target

The phrasing is odd, but I would interpret that to mean

> you can cause the hand to reach for a different creature [than the one currently grappled] or to move...

I would say the use of different does not constitute any limitations on re-targeting a creature that has escaped. There is no language specifically stating it and no logical reason why it would be the case so it seems like the hand is able to re-attempt the grab.